# Parsing combination english and arabic data in xml

Tags: java, xml-parsing

i've a java application that parses xml files each file contains combination between Arabic (right to left) and English (left to right) data, the problem that these data comes from the backend with a lot of tabs and spaces between them and there is no way to change them on backend, and when i'm trying to split such data i found that the order of the words not correct although before removing the tabs the order was fine, the problem occurs a lot when there is combination between Arabic and English words

example for combination

```
String combinationString = "بمبلغ       2867.51     ريال سعودي      رقم العملية     LD1131900120";
combinationString.split("/t");
```

Comment: Can you tell us in the example what the correct order would be?

Comment: for the above example it should be like that
LD1131900120 بمبلغ 2867.51 ريال سعودي رقم العملية

Comment: So 5, 1, 2, 3, 4? (if you number them from left to right)
Is it always like that?

Comment: LD1131900120 this word change the direction because the previous word is arabic and this is english

Comment: Okay, but is it always like that? (why are the numbers seen as arabic? Are they actually 15.7682?)
I'm asking because if they are always the same, you could take off the TAB and the LD1131900120, and append them to the front (LDwhatever first, then then tab), and then split by /t. Yes, it's rather lame, but I don't see how else you're gonna solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Running that example code through `native2ascii` we get

```
String combinationString = "\u0628\u0645\u0628\u0644\u063a      2867.51  \u0631\u064a\u0627\u0644 \u0633\u0639\u0648\u062f\u064a        \u0631\u0642\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u0639\u0645\u0644\u064a\u0629   LD1131900120";
combinationString.split("/t");
```

Now we can see clearly that the string contains five tab-separated fields in the following (logical) order:

1. بمبلغ (\u0628\u0645\u0628\u0644\u063a)
2. 2867.51
3. ريال سعودي (\u0631\u064a\u0627\u0644 \u0633\u0639\u0648\u062f\u064a)
4. رقم العملية (\u0631\u0642\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u0639\u0645\u0644\u064a\u0629)
5. LD1131900120

The confusion arises when you try and display this logical sequence of characters - the apparent word order depends on whether the context in which you are displaying the text is assumed to be mainly LTR with some embedded RTL text or vice-versa.  Essentially the bidirectional display algorithm splits up the text into maximal contiguous LTR and RTL runs of text, with things like punctuation and numbers handled according to the rules of the surrounding language.  You have two segments in this example, the first from RTL (بمبلغ                2867.51         ريال سعودي               رقم العملية) and the second from LTR (LD1131900120).

Once the maximal segments have been determined, the display algorithm then arranges those segments according to the principal direction of the display environment.  If the environment is mainly LTR you'll get segment 1 on the left and segment 2 on the right:

> ‪بمبلغ                2867.51         ريال سعودي               رقم العملية       LD1131900120‬

But if the environment is mainly RTL you'll get segment 1 on the right and segment 2 on the left:

> ‫بمبلغ                2867.51         ريال سعودي               رقم العملية       LD1131900120‬

[There are control characters you can add to override this behaviour](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr9/#Explicit_Directional_Embeddings) - that's how I did the examples above, it's the same text in both but with different surrounding control characters.  In example 1 I force the string into LTR context by prefixing it with U+202A (LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING) and suffixing it with U+202C (POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING), in example 2 I force it into RTL context by prefixing U+202B (RIGHT-TO-LEFT EMBEDDING) and suffixing U+202C.  You can do the same in Java

```
String rtlContext = "\u202b" + someString + "\u202c";
```